# PHP - Check if JSON value exists in Array and get the associated user_id if it does

Tags: php, arrays

I have created a quiz on my website and I am storing the quiz results as a JSON element in my database. I am then creating a PHP array with the user's ID and which quizzes they've taken and their results. The array looks like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [user_id] => 167
        [quizzes_complete] => [{"ID":"210","date":"01/31/19","score":"8"},{"ID":"202","date":"07/30/20","score":"10"}] 
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [user_id] => 686
        [quizzes_complete] => [{"ID":"83","date":"03/27/19","score":"9"}]
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [user_id] => 279
        [quizzes_complete] => [{"ID":"210","date":"03/27/19","score":"7"}]
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [user_id] => 239
        [quizzes_complete] => [{"ID":"83","date":"03/27/19","score":"8"}]
    )
)
```

What I would like to do is loop through this array and search for a specific quiz `ID` and then build an array of `user_id`s for the users which have completed that specific quiz. So let's say I want to find the `user_id` of each user who completed quiz with the ID `210`, how would I go about building that array of users? Here is what I've tried, but I think I'm pretty far off:

```
$usersCompletedQuiz = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($userCompletedQuizzes); $i++) {
    if (in_array('"ID":"210"', $userCompletedQuizzes)) {
        array_push($usersCompletedQuiz, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

For Quiz `210` I would expect the `$usersCompletedQuiz` array to look like this:

```
(167,279)
```

Since those are the users who have completed that quiz.

Comment: It doesn't help in this situation, but you shouldn't be storing the JSON in a column.  You should have a related table with columns for the quiz info.  Then you can get it in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AbraCadaver [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63944729/php-check-if-json-value-exists-in-array-and-get-the-associated-user-id-if-it-d#comment113074677_63944729), the ideal is to insert the json with the quiz information in a table, with each index being a column. That way it would be possible to get the data you need with a query in the database.

BUT, if you are unable to perform this action at this time, here's a code of how you can get what you need:

```
// Array of users, with id and completed quizzes.
$userCompletedQuizzes = array(
    array(
        'user_id' => 167,
        'quizzes_complete' => '[{"ID":"210","date":"01/31/19","score":"8"},{"ID":"202","date":"07/30/20","score":"10"}]'
    ),
    array(
        'user_id' => 686,
        'quizzes_complete' => '[{"ID":"83","date":"03/27/19","score":"9"}]'
    ),
    array(
        'user_id' => 279,
        'quizzes_complete' => '[{"ID":"210","date":"03/27/19","score":"7"}]'
    ),
    array(
        'user_id' => 239,
        'quizzes_complete' => '[{"ID":"83","date":"03/27/19","score":"8"}]'
    ),
);

$quizId = 210; // The requested quiz id
$usersCompletedQuiz = array();
foreach($userCompletedQuizzes as $key => $userInfo) {
    /*
        Convert the json with the data of the
        completed quizzes and return the id and date
        of each one to the variable $userQuizzes
    */
    $userQuizzes = array_map(function($ui) {
        return ['id' => $ui->ID, 'date' => $ui->date];
    }, json_decode($userInfo['quizzes_complete']));
    
    // Check if the required id is in the user's quizzes array
    foreach($userQuizzes as $uq) {
        if($quizId == $uq['id']) {
            array_push(
                $usersCompletedQuiz,
                [
                    'user_id' => $userInfo['user_id'],
                    'date' => DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y', $uq['date'])->format('Y-m-d')
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
print_r($usersCompletedQuiz);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 167
    [1] => 279
)
```

Sort example:

```
usort($usersCompletedQuiz, function($u1, $u2) {
    if($u1['date'] == $u2['date']) return $u1['user_id'] > $u2['user_id'];
    return $u1['date'] > $u2['date'];
});
```

Comment: Works a treat, thank you! I will definitely keep that in mind for the future, unfortunately I am working with years old data and don't feel comfortable enough with SQL to do the conversion.

Comment: You're welcome! I figured you couldn't otherwise handle this data at the moment. But if you keep that in mind, that's fine.

Comment: Would it also be possible to add the date which they completed the course to the `$usersCompletedQuiz` array? I would like to be able to sort the array by the date in which the quiz was completed.

Comment: Of course, I'll edit the answer to include this request.